# Python .net framework reference argument Double[]&

Tags: python, .net, ironpython, python.net

Using the Python for .Net framework I'm trying to call a method from a C# .dll file. This method has the following arguments:

```
public static void ExternalFunction(
    String Arg1,
    ref Double[]& Arg2,
);
```

I understood the .Net framework converts Python floats to doubles. Now I would like to know how to make an array (double) and pass this as a reference to the external method.

I've the following code:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("MyDll")
from MyLib import MyClass

myName = "Benjamin"

r = MyClass.ExternalFunction(myName, 0.0);
print "Result: %s"%r
```

Comment: http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#methods-with-ref-or-out-parameters

Comment: I actually wasn't planning to use Ironpython. I believe it's not necessarily in this case. But if it is, I'll be willing to step over to Ironpython.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call this method by providing a list (or tuple) of floats as a second parameter.

```
MyClass.ExternalFunction(myName, [0.0]);
```

There will be a conversion between  2 different data structures in 2 virtual machines. Python.Net will convert python's list of floats to an array of doubles in .Net  environment and pass it by reference to your function. Changes made to  second parameter **will not** be propagated back to python.

By using reflection you can get more control over parameters marshaling.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("MyDll")
import System
import MyLib

myClassType = System.Type.GetType("MyLib.MyClass, MyDll") 
method = myClassType.GetMethod("ExternalFunction")
numbersArray = System.Array[System.Double]([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
parameters = System.Array[System.Object](["Benjamin",numbersArray])
method.Invoke(None,parameters)


numbersArray = parameters[1] # an updated Arg2 can be retrieved from parameters array
```