# Passing bytes as parameter to c#?

Tags: c#, python, .net, python-3.x, python.net

I am currently stuck while trying to call a c# methods from python. I am using python 3.2 and not IronPython. I used pip to install the latest version of python.net

Problem occurs (as often discussed) while using ref or out parameters.

Here is my code so far:

```
import clr

path = clr.FindAssembly("USB_Adapter_Driver")
clr.AddReference(path)
from USB_Adapter_Driver import USB_Adapter
gpio = USB_Adapter()

version2 = ''
status, version = gpio.version(version2)
print ('status: ' + str(status))
print ('Version: ' + str(version))

readMask = bytearray([1])
writeData = bytearray([0])

print (readMask)
print (writeData)

status, readData = gpio.gpioReadWrite(b'\x01',b'\x00',b'\x00')
status, readData = gpio.gpioReadWrite(readMask[0],writeData[0],b'\x00')
status, readData = gpio.gpioReadWrite(readMask[0],writeData[0],)
```

I have had some major issues getting clr. running at all. But in this exact config it seems to work (I need to save the path to a variable, otherwise it wont work, I also cant type the path the dll in clr.AddReference(path) because this wont work as well)

The c# version method looks like this:

```
public USB_Adapter_Driver.USB_Adapter.Status version(ref string ver)
```

My status variable gets a value which works perfectly with the status enum for the c# class.

Problem is: after the call my variable "version" is empty. Why? According to: [How to use a .NET method which modifies in place in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600315/how-to-use-a-net-method-which-modifies-in-place-in-python) this should be a legal way to do things. I also tried to use the explicit version but my namespace clr does not contain clr.Reference().

The next (and more severe) problem is pio.gpioReadWrite().Here the info about this one:

```
public USB_Adapter_Driver.USB_Adapter.Status gpioReadWrite(byte readMask, byte writeData, ref byte readData)
```

Here I get the error message:

```
TypeError: No method matches given arguments
```

It doesn't matter which of the calls I use from above. All of them fail.

Here is the full output of a debugging run:

```
d:\[project path]\tests.py(6)<module>()
status: 6
Version: 
bytearray(b'\x01')
bytearray(b'\x00')
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
d:\[project path]\tests.py(28)<module>()
status, readData = gpio.gpioReadWrite(readMask[0],writeData[0],)
(Pdb) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\pdb.py", line 1661, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "D:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\pdb.py", line 1542, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "D:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\bdb.py", line 431, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\[project path]\tests.py", line 28, in <module>
    status, readData = gpio.gpioReadWrite(readMask[0],writeData[0],)
TypeError: No method matches given arguments
```

Hope one of you has an idea on how to fix this.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: You can use the branch from this pull request to get ref/out working with pythonnet: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/227

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/226

Answer (score 2):

Python.Net doesn't handle ref/out parameters like IronPython.
`status, readData = gpio.gpioReadWrite(b'\x01',b'\x00',b'\x00')` call is not quite correct since Python.Net will not return an updated readData as second result.
You can handle ref parameters using reflection. Check out my answer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484167/python-net-framework-reference-argument-double/18467165#18467165)

there is a rough code template for your case:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("USB_Adapter_Driver")
import System
import USB_Adapter_Driver

myClassType = System.Type.GetType("USB_Adapter_Driver.USB_Adapter, USB_Adapter_Driver") 
method = myClassType.GetMethod("gpioReadWrite")
parameters = System.Array[System.Object]([System.Byte(1),System.Byte(0),System.Byte(0)])
gpio = USB_Adapter_Driver.USB_Adapter()
status = method.Invoke(gpio,parameters)
readData = parameters[2]
```

Comment: Hi Gosha, thanks for the help so far. If I run the code as-is I get the error, that system.object[] cant be converted to system.byte (in line 11). I changed line 9 to use System.Array[System.Byte] but I now get the error: status = method.Invoke(gpio,parameters)
TypeError: No method matches given arguments. Any Idea on how to solve that?