# Using Python.NET to call a C# function, yet keep getting a TypeError

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, python.net

I'm trying to use the [Rant procedural text generator](http://berkin.me/rant/) in my Python program via Python.NET. I'm testing it out by using the example code from the [documentation](http://berkin.me/rantdocs/getting-started/developers/) on the main Rant website. I am able to import the Rant classes into my Python program, but when I get to the `rant.Do(pgm)` part of the example, the whole program falls to pieces.

My code sort of looks like this (I have been mainly doing this from the Python command line interpreter):

```
import clr
import System
lib_dir = '/path/to/Rant.dll'
clr.AddReference(lib_dir)
from Rant import RantProgram
from Rant import RantEngine
from Rant import RantProgramArgs as args
rant = RantEngine
pgm = RantProgram.CompileString('[numfmt:verbal][rep:10][sep:,\s]{[rn]}')
# Here's where the program occurs.
output = rant.Do(pgm)
```

The problem happens when I try to use the `Do()` method in the object `rant`. When I run this, it gives the error `TypeError: No method matches given arguments`. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37789281/1533147) because it suggests putting in all of the arguments for that method.

The method arguments for the `Do()` method include the following (this is what I've gotten from calling `help(RantEngine)` ):

```
Rant.RantOutput Do(Rant.RantProgram, Int32, Double, Rant.RantProgramArgs)
Rant.RantOutput Do(Rant.RantProgram, Rant.RNG, Int32, Double, Rant.RantProgramArgs)
Rant.RantOutput Do(Rant.RantProgram, Int64, Int32, Double, Rant.RantProgramArgs)
```

I have tried using the first one. So I have tried calling a method like this:

```
rant.Do(pgm, System.Int32(1), System.Double(2), args)
```

Sadly, it still gives me a `TypeError`.

So how can I get the example code to run under Python?

Comment: What is `args` really? More specifically, what is that line `from Rant import RantProgramArgs as args` telling you about args?

Comment: Those are the Rant arguments which I you pass to the pattern. At least, I think that's what it is from this [API reference](http://berkin.me/rantdocs/api/#dorantprogram-int-double-rantprogramargs-method).

Comment: I guess you need to learn/refresh some basics about Python. Look up the documentation of what "[from Module import Identifier as LocalName](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html)" really means/does. Remember, programming is not you believing something and hoping the computer/compiler will somehow agree with your beliefs. Hint: `args` in your question are not the arguments which you pass, `args` is the type of the arguments you should pass... ;-)

Comment: the problem is this line: `rant = RantEngine`, it should be `rant = RantEngine()`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @denfromufa. That did the job.